# Where to find GUI code

Tags: unity, gui, c++, c

I've been rummaging through Unity's source code (Shell Interface) and I was a little curious about something; where in the code are you supposed to find positional code? I'll clarify a bit with some examples. How do you find in the code what tells the Launcher to sit on the left side of the screen? Where in the code does it tell the "Session" button on the panel (top) to sit at the very right of the screen?

I guess my real question is how do I find this out for myself? I've looked through a big portion of the source code and can't find anything related to the actual position of these items, only their sub-items like text-align. Any guidance on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Find (using rummaging tools like `grep`) where, in the source, the object (Launcher, Session button) is created, and look at the details of how it is created.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the positioning of the laucher:

if you search the [source code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unity-team/unity/trunk/view/head:/launcher/Launcher.cpp) for 'geometry', 'width', 'height' and so on, you will encounter the function [Launcher::Resize](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unity-team/unity/trunk/view/head:/launcher/Launcher.cpp#L1533), which sets the launcher's window geometry.

Looking at the callers of this function ([Launcher::SetIconSize](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unity-team/unity/trunk/view/head:/launcher/Launcher.cpp#L1515) and [Launcher::OnMonitorChanged](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unity-team/unity/trunk/view/head:/launcher/Launcher.cpp#L1209)), you will quickly find out, that the launcher is indeed positioned at the to left corner of the display and has full height (minus the height of the panel).

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/share/themes` contains all of the customization options for a Unity theme.

Let me know if you find these specific settings in there for your theme.